# How to implement API Pagination and call the API with incremented values for Pagination in a React Web App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried the pagination in this code by taking `pageToken:""` as the initial value. I am receiving 30 data with get requests using Axios, and I want to add pagination to my code on every page I want 5 results and the page starts with 0, how to implement pagination?

```
import axios from "axios";

export const BASE_URL = "https://youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com";

const options = {
  params: {
    maxResults: 30,
    pageToken: "",
  },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

export const fetchFromAPI = async (url, page) => {
  options.params.pageToken = page > 0 ? String(page) : "";

  const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${url}`, options);

  return data;
};
```

Comment: @roanjain After implementing your approach I am getting 5 as maxResultsPerPage but how would I get remaining results which are 25 results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can update the `fetchFromAPI` to include following

```js
  const maxResultsPerPage = 5;
  const startIndex = page * maxResultsPerPage;

  options.params.maxResults = maxResultsPerPage;
```

Comment: How I can start from page 0 and then call API with incremented values for Pagination.

Comment: pass the initial value for page as 1

Comment: Does it mean that value of pageToken is to be 1 ?